# Two graph theory problems

Tags: graph-theory, trees, bipartite-graphs

I've been studying graph theory recently and I find it very interesting. But since I'm studying it on my own, I feel like I'm missing something - for example, I'm struggling with these two problems:

1. If for whichever two vertices a and b in the graph G there is only one simple path from a to b, then the graph is a tree.

Eh... isn't this part of the definition for a tree? I really don't even know where to start with proving this statements. I would really like to see a good proof laid out, so if anyone can help, please do! :)

Another one:
2. Find which complete bipartite graphs are complete.

What does it mean which COMPLETE bipartite graphs are complete? Can a complete bipartite graph not be complete? I would also love to see a good solution to this. It's really interesting and it bother's me that I can't solve it.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: A complete graph has an edge between any two vertices. A complete bipartite graph has an edge between any two vertices on "opposite sides".

Comment: Yes, (1) is by definition!

Comment: Yes indeed, but does this imply that no bipartite graph is complete?

Comment: There are many equivalent definitions for a tree in graph theory. The solution of problem 1 will depend very much on just how trees are defined in your textbook. Instead of asking us what the definition of a tree is, why don't **you tell us**?

Comment: A graph is *complete* if every vertex is adjacent to every other vertex. However, *complete bipartite graph* does **not** mean "graph which is complete and bipartite". Rather, it's a bipartite graph whose vertices can be divided into two classes, let's call them "red" and "blue", so that every red vertex is adjacent to every blue vertex.  It's as complete as can be for a bipartite graph; add one more edge and it's no longer bipartite.

Comment: For example, the graph $K_3$ is a complete graph which is not bipartite; the graph $P_4$ is bipartite but not complete, nor even complete bipartite; the graph $K_{2,2}$ aka $C_4$ is a complete bipartite graph, but not a complete graph; the graph $K_2$ aka $K_{1,1}$ is both a complete graph and a complete bipartite graph.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel (1) is by definition ***if*** that's how trees are defined. If trees are defined as connected acyclic graphs, then (1) requires a proof.

Comment: @bof I know, right? But a proof should be easy: if a cycle exists there are two simple paths between two vertices of the cycle.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel That's a proof of the **converse** of the OP's problem 1. The OP has to prove that, if there are two different $uv$-paths, then there is a (simple) cycle in the graph. That's takes a bit more proving.

Comment: @bof I don't have a textbook for this, I am learning online. :) The definition I know is: A tree is an undirected graph in which any two vertices are connected by exactly one path.

Is there any way at all you could help me with proving this? :)

Comment: I actually managed to find this awesome proof! http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~gptesler/184a/slides/184a_trees_17-handout.pdf on slide 3